# generating graph and PHP_INT_MAX

Tags: php, graph

I'm reading "PHP 7 Data Structures and Algorithms" chapter "Shortest path using the Floyd-Warshall algorithm"
the author is generating a graph with this code:

```
$totalVertices = 5;
$graph = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < $totalVertices; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < $totalVertices; $j++) {
        $graph[$i][$j] = $i == $j ? 0 : PHP_INT_MAX;
    }
}
```

i don't understand this line :

```
$graph[$i][$j] = $i == $j ? 0 : PHP_INT_MAX;
```

looks like a one line if statement

is it the same as ?

```
if ($i == $j) {
    $graph[$i][$j] = 0;
} else {
    $graph[$i][$j] = PHP_INT_MAX;
}
```

what is the point of using PHP_INT_MAX ?
at the end what does the graph look like  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've correctly understood the ternary (`? :`) operator

To answer the other part of your question, have a look if the following makes sense to you.

**First:**
The author initializes the `$graph` array using the following code:

```
<?php
$totalVertices = 5; // total nodes (use 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4 instead of A, B, C, D, and E, respectively)
$graph = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < $totalVertices; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < $totalVertices; $j++) {
        $graph[$i][$j] = $i == $j ? 0 : PHP_INT_MAX;
    }
}
```

which results in the following matrix
[image]

All the nodes(vertices) on the main diagonal(grey) are set to 0 as a node's distance to itself equals 0.

All the remaining nodes in the 'matrix' are set to `PHP_INT_MAX` (the largest integer supported) - we'll see why this is in a minute.

**Second:**
The author then sets the distances between the nodes that have a direct connection(edges), writing them manually to the `$graph` array, as follows:

```
$graph[0][1] = $graph[1][0] = 10;
$graph[2][1] = $graph[1][2] = 5;
$graph[0][3] = $graph[3][0] = 5;
$graph[3][1] = $graph[1][3] = 5;
$graph[4][1] = $graph[1][4] = 10;
$graph[3][4] = $graph[4][3] = 20;
```

This results in the following 'matrix' stored in array `$graph` (green: edge distances):
[image]

So why does the author use `PHP_INT_MAX` for the nodes that are not directly connected(the non-edges)?

> The reason is, because it allows for the algorithm to work with
>   node-connection(edge) distances up to and including `PHP_INT_MAX`.

In this particular example, any number smaller than 20 in stead of `PHP_INT_MAX` in the ternary would warp the outcomes of the algorithm - it would spit out wrong results.

Or another way to look at this, in this particular example the author could have just used any number bigger than 20 in stead of `PHP_INT_MAX` to get satisfactory results from the algorithm,
because the biggest distance between two directly connected nodes in this case equals 20. Use any number smaller than 20 and the results will come out wrong.

You can give it a try, and test:

`$graph[$i][$j] = $i == $j ? 0 : 19;`

the algorithm will now tell us that the shortest distance between A to E - i.e. `$graph[0][4]` equals 19... **WRONG**

So using `PHP_INT_MAX` here gives *'leeway'*, it allows for the algorithm to work successfully with edge distances smaller than or equal to 9223372036854775807 (the largest int that can be stored on a 64 bit system),
or 2147483647 (on a 32 bit system).

Answer (score 1):

You have two questions here.

The first is regarding the syntax `condition ? val_if_true : val_if_false`. This is called the "ternary operator". Your assessment regarding the behavior is correct.

The second is regarding the use of `PHP_INT_MAX`. All distances between two nodes are being initialized to one of two values: `0` if nodes `i` and `j` are the same node (i.e. a vertex), and `PHP_INT_MAX` if the nodes are not the same (i.e. an edge). That is, a node's distance to itself is `0` and a node's distance to any other node is the largest integer value PHP recognizes. The reason for this is that the Floyd-Warshall algorithm utilizes the concept of "infinity" to represent minimum distances that have not yet been calculated, but as there is no concept of "infinity" in PHP, the value `PHP_INT_MAX` is being used as a stand-in for it.